# DAX measure with interim table doesn't work as expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a problem with a DAX measure in Power BI which doesn't work as expected. I would like to calculate the NSV Volume Effect based on the deviation between last and current year sales (pre-calculated measure [SalesSBA vs PY abs]) multiplied with the NSV per Unit of last year (values can be found in the linked matrix below).

The code is as following (the filter in the formula limits the calculation to pieces):

```
NSV Volume Effect = 

VAR InterimTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FACT_SalesSBA,
            DIM_Product[Product],
            DIM_Date[Date],
            DIM_PlanningGroup[Planning Group]
        ),
        "NSV Volume Effect Single", CALCULATE(FACT_SalesSBA[SalesSBA vs PY abs],FILTER(ALL(DIM_SalesFacts),DIM_SalesFacts[Sales Facts]=130))*FACT_SalesSBA[SalesSBA NSV per Unit PY]
    )
RETURN

SUMX(
    InterimTable,
    [NSV Volume Effect Single]
)
```

I've included the interim result of the measure ([NSV Volume Effect Single]) for debugging as a seperate measure in the matrix (link below). At that point, everything is just fine. But as soon, as the SUMX comes into account, the measure looses all those results, where we have only prior year NSV and no current one.

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to paste images inside hte post yet, so please have a look at the Power BI matrix with all columns under this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INnnj.png

Any help is appreciated!
Many thanks
Axel

Comment: Can you add the code for  [SalesSBA vs PY abs] measure? Generally, if syntax is ok, then the problem is in filtering.

Comment: The code of the measure is in our DWH, it's simply A-B. On the visual itself, there is no filtering.